# Getting strange failure when deploying the Java quickstart app to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api

The Java Quickstart app has completely stopped working for me for some reason.   i thought I had messed something up but now I'm not sure what the issue is.  Anyone know what's going on?  I'm using App Engine 1.8.5.  Here's the error in the log I get right after auth'ing for the first time:

> 2013-10-10 14:28:23.230 /index.jsp 500 25ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36
>   199.2.242.199 - - [10/Oct/2013:14:28:23 -0700] "GET /index.jsp HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69
>   Safari/537.36" "clear-numbers.appspot.com" ms=25 cpu_ms=47
>   app_engine_release=1.8.5
>   instance=00c61b117c38bd00fd55598f54971f44e7e43a52 C 2013-10-10
>   14:28:23.227 Uncaught exception from servlet
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(ResourceFileServlet.java:342)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(ResourceFileServlet.java:281)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.ResourceFileServlet.doGet(ResourceFileServlet.java:142)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at com.google.glassware.ReauthFilter.doFilter(ReauthFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at com.google.glassware.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
>     at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: Just want to add that it's always worked locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some references to Jetty in that stack trace. The current version of the Java quick start does not support deployment to App Engine. It can be deployed to a standard J2EE container such as Jetty that it uses out of the box.

If you'd like to deploy to App Engine there's an [old tag](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/releases/tag/app-engine) for the final version that worked on App Engine, but it does not include any new API features added after May 2013.

Comment: <facepalm>..the maddening thing is that it deploys to AE fine and runs fine until it doesn't.  Looks like I'm switching to Python.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Is there any way to make the current version of the quick start able to be deployed to app engine?

Comment: @hichris123 Yup. Make two changes: 1) replace the credential store with an AppEngineCredentialStore (part of the Java client library) and 2) switch the HTTP client factory to one that works on App Engine like UrlFetch